# viscose not showing connected device at the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm sure there was a place for selecting device...if connected, it show phone like SM960 , or iPhone .
but suddenly, I can't see this also I can't run code from play button on vscode. (start without debugging)

what happened?

Answer (score 2):

It is Easy Just right click on The vs code Bottom Bar. You will Get a list of Item then Click on Flutter devices,[image]

Answer (score 1):

Close the `VSCode` and again open `VSCode` as Admin. Than it will show the connected Devices.

Answer (score 0):

The vscode flutter pluggin must be used with vscode oppened as admin.
Make sure to use

> ctrl+ shift +p

to select device

Answer (score 0):

install Flutter extension.
⇧⌘X . and install Flutter

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem.